# How to pipe selected property from one gremlin query to another?

Tags: gremlin, graph-databases, tinkerpop, janusgraph, tinkerpop3

I'm trying to pass the selected properties from one traversal to another. But it is not working with pure gremlin way.

```
g.V().has('pname', name).has('version', within(V().has('ecosystem', ecosystem).has('name', name).values('latest_version', 'latest_non_cve_version').))
```

However it works when I split the above query into multiple statements.

```
x = g.V().has('ecosystem', ecosystem).has('name', name).values('latest_version', 'latest_non_cve_version').toList(); g.V().has('pname', name).has('version', within(x))
```

Is there a way to achieve the same with pure gremlin way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `within` predicate cannot take a traversal. You should be able to do what you need by simply reversing the two parts of the query. As I don't have your data I am showing an example that uses the air-routes data set. The query you need will end up being something like this:

```
gremlin> g.V().has('region',within('US-NM','US-TX')).
               values('region').
               fold().as('a').
           V().hasLabel('airport').
               where(within('a')).
                 by('region').
                 by().
               count()
==>36
```